# How to pull a certain file type into a list Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to pull images from my Asset folder into a list. Within my asset folder I have another folder called images and in there I have 2 `.jpeg` files. When I pull the images into a list with the code below it also pulls 3 random `.png` files that are not in the folder. It seems the other 3 random `.png` files are "android default" files but I cant seem to get rid of them.

Image of list structure:

[image: Image of list structure]

Is there any way to pull only jpeg files into the list, or is there a way to delete these other android default files.

```
 String[] imageList = getAssets().list("images");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Collectors` if you target API under level 24.
Plus `lambda` requires java 8.

Try this.

```
// Your filename list    
String[] imageList = getAssets().list("images");

// New list 
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

// For each file name, if the filename ends with jpg or jpeg, add it into "my list"
for(String filename : imageList) {
    if(filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
        myList.add(filename);
    }
}
```

Then, you will have a List of String*s* with only JPEG, jpeg, JPG, jpg files

Comment: Thanks so much, I will give this a go

Comment: @NicholasMott My pleasure. Don't forget to set the answer as validated please

Answer (score 1):

In both the following solutions the filenames that end with `.jpg` are filtered and then added to a list.

- To get only the .jpg files use :

  ```
  List<String> myFiles = Files.list(Paths.get(PATH))
                       .filter(s -> s.toString().endsWith(".jpg"))
                       .map(Path::getFileName)
                       .map(Object::toString)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- To filter after loading all files use :

  ```
  List<String> myFiles = Arrays.asList(imageList)
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.endsWith(".jpg"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```